# SSH is running, but not listening on the assigned port

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

Recently I found I could no longer SSH into two of my Linux machines running Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS. They have always been setup on port 43210, and have worked since at least 2018.  After a recent reboot, I could no longer connect using that port.  When I look to see if the service is running using the service command I get:

```
service ssh status
ssh start/running
```

So it appears to be running.  However when I attempt to use `lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN`
or `netstat -tunlp` I do not see the server listening on any port. 

I checked for firewalls (to the extent I know how), and both ufw and iptables appear to be disabled.

```
ufw status
Status: inactive
```

and

```
iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source                   destination

Chain FORWARD(policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source                   destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source                   destination
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled OpenSSH-Server using apt with no change.  The version currently installed is 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.13

My settings in sshd_config:(hand copied as I cannot cut and paste, please forgive my poor typing)

```
#comments
Port 43210
#comments
Protocol 2
#comments
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

#comments
UsePrivilegeSeperation yes

#comments
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

#comments
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG

#Comments
LoginGraceTime 120
#comments
PermitRootLoing no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#comments

#comments
IgnoreRhosts yes
#comment
RhostsRSAAuthenticaion no
#comment
HostbasedAuthentication no
#comments

#comment
PermitEmptyPasswords no

#comments
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

#comments

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLasLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#comment

#comments
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

#comments
UsePAM yes
```

When I attempt to connect using:

```
ssh <ip address> -p 43210
ssh: connect to host <ip address> port 43210: Connection refused
```

I don't know if it is directly related, but logs do not appear to be updating either even though syslog-ng appears to be running.  This was discovered around the same time as the ssh failure.

I'm sure there is information I'm omitting.  Let me know what else I can provide to help clarify the issue.

###### Edit 1

```
service ssh stop
/usr/sbin/sshd -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.01f 6 Jan 2014 
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker 
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA 
debug1: private host key #0 type 1 RSA 
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker 
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA 
debug 1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA 
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA 
debug1: private host key: #2 type 3 ECDSA 
debug1: private host key: #3 type 4 ED25519 
/var/run/sshd must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
```

```
ls -ld /var/ /var/run /var/run/sshd
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Oct 24 09:46 /var/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    4 May 13  2015 /var/run -> /run
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   40 Oct 14 07:43 /var/run/sshd
```

Comment: What is the output of running `sshd` in debug mode? That means (a) stop any running `sshd` processes, and then (b) run `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`.

Comment: `sshd` will be writing either to the `systemd` logging service or else to one of the files in `/var/log`. You need to look at the output from the service and see what it's telling you. Start with `systemctl --full --no-pager status ssh` and add that to your question

Comment: (1) Execute `nmap` from client to get the open Ports on the Server (2) Execute `strace` on the `SSHD` Process to check where it is hanging (3A) Change the Port number in your config & try (3B) Also try it on the Default Port : Whether that works or not , we will get Debug Points

Comment: When it says **"ssh start/running"** that indicates it is hanging , I think it should say **"ssh running"** : There may be Some Issue in your Network Stack.

Comment: @larsks when I check ownership of /var/run/sshd it's owned by root:root.

Comment: @roaima systemctl: command not found.

Comment: @Prem nmap shows neither 22 nore 43210 open.  I have moved it back to 22 and the port doesn't show open in the commands above, and nmap does't show any new ports open.  client machine is windows and  I don't have strace on that to my knowledge.

Comment: @Prem Re: comment #2.  If it helps troublshoot the network, I can see the websites running on that machine from the client machine, so nginx is running.

Comment: Re `systemctl` - sorry my mistake; I misread you using `service`. In this case run (as root) `grep -lF sshd /var/log/*` (first flag is lowercase L) to see which files you're getting sshd log messages written to. Probably `auth` and `daemon.log` amongst others. Check those to see what it's telling you

Comment: "_/var/run/sshd must be owned by root and not group or world-writable_" please add `ls -ld /var /var/run /var/run/sshd` to your question. Not as a comment.

Comment: @roaima re: grep -lF sshd /var/log/* came up with an error about a directory but no other results.  I updated to grep -lrF sshd /var/log/* and found /var/log/debian-acig/<datestamp>/ACIGCCIP-NEW2.auth.  There are a lot of files.  the last log file was 20221017 (before this issue started).

Comment: You have to Execute `strace` on the Linux Server itself. Use `ps | grep sshd` to get the SSHD PID , then Execute `strace -p PID` as root. You could `kill` the Current SSHD Process & try starting it with `strace` to check what activities it is going through & where it is hanging.

Comment: @Prem I think we have determined ssh isn't actually running.  I misunderstood the output (system administration is not my primary job duty, and I'm learning on the fly... sorry).  So ssh is not running, and the error has something to do with permissions on the /var/run/sshd directory... ?  I have edited the question above with additional details.

Comment: @larsks I have updated my question with the output from /usr/sbin/sshd -d above as well as the commend ls -ld /var /var/run /var/run/sshd.  Sorry about the mess I made with last comment regarding this command.

Comment: I was going by your line that SSHD was running. Use `chmod` to make the Permission `700` , only root will have full access & everybody else will have no access.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks to everyone for the assist.  Prem, if you write it up I'll select it as the answer.